# Android make image front layered

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, I ran in to a small problem with the layout, the image I have is under the textboxes, so I can't really see the image, can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order in your XML Layout:

from this: (in this case the image under the EditText):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_img"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="text"/>
```

to this: (the image above the EditText):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="text"/>    
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_img"/>
```